# Why can't I specify how a file is opened?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following code:

```
try:
    f = open("myfile2.dat", "rb")
except IOError:
    f = open("myfile2.dat", "ab+")
print(f.mode)
f.close()
```

If myfile2.dat doesn't exist when I run this code Idle opens a new file with rb+ not ab+, why?

Comment: what output you're getting?

Comment: did you run your code twice without deleting the file myfile2.dat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are opening a *new* file in append + write mode. Because there is no file to append *to*, you get one in read + write mode instead.

This is *essentially* the same thing. There is no problem here, you can still both read from *and* write to the file.

Under the hood, the file is still open in append mode, but the `.mode` attribute gives a simpler view on the file; it merely will report what you can do with the file *now*, not what happened when you opened the file. It shows only if you can read or write the file and if the file was opened for exclusive creating (`x` mode).

See the [C code for the `.mode` attribute](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_io/fileio.c#l1002).

*Update*: Yes, this is confusing, and really a bug. The [path to fix this discrepancy](http://bugs.python.org/issue18876) has recently been merged into Python, and when new releases of Python 2.7, 3.3 and 3.4 come out file objects' `.mode` attribute will better reflect the original mode string used to open the file.

Comment: It's worth noting that the semantics of opening in "append" mode may vary from one operating system to another. Many treat it identically to opening in `r+` mode immediately followed by a seek to the end of the file. Only a few OSs treat it differently, with all writes forced to be at the end.

Comment: Sure, but the `ab+` mode is *only* used when the file did not exist; so the file is *always* empty. Thus there is no previous data to append *to* and using a `r+` is perfectly correct here.

Comment: My point is that some OSs enforce writes always being at the end, even if you seek to another location. So if you write `"foo"`, then seek back to the start of the file and write `"bar"`, you may have `"bar"` in the file, or `"foobar"` depending on your OS. Since this behavior is pretty rare, I would not be surprised if both you and the questioner are on OSs where `a+` is identical to `r+` (plus a seek), but I just wanted to point out that that may not always be the case.

Comment: I think that's the explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Disregard this, this was done on Python 2.x, I did not see the #python-3.x tag in the original question.

It opened ab+ for me:

```
>>> try:
...     f = open("myfile2.dat", "rb")
... except IOError:
...     f = open("myfile2.dat", "ab+")
... 
>>> print(f.mode)
ab+
```

This is running Jython on a Mac.

Comment: That is not the same thing as Python 3 by far.

Comment: To be explicit: I can reproduce what the OP sees in Python 3.3; the I/O handling was completely overhauled for Python 3.

Comment: @mistermarko: No, I reproduced what you see, it is just *not a problem*.